# Buy X get Y - How can I understand the math behind it?

Tags: c

I'm confused about the math behind buy X get Y. In case of BOGO, it's easy to calculate the amount of goods you want and the amount of money you have to pay. For example, when you want 4 you just have to buy 2 and pay for 2, but what about buy 3 get 1 free, or buy 30 get 1 free. I find it quite easy to calculate that in my head, but when I try to find an equation that represents this situation, I couldn't (I think because of my weak math base).

###### Problem description

> Calculate Total Cost after Subtracting Quantity of Free Promotional Products
> Each laundry detergent product sold by the store to consumers costs X VND.
> The store has a promotion: for every 10 products purchased (excluding the additional free ones), you get 1 product for free.
> The customer wants to buy n products. Calculate the total amount the customer has to pay for those n products.
> The input is the price of a product and the number of products the customer buys
> The output will be the amount the customer must pay (take up to 2 decimal places)

```
INPUT
50000 12
OUTPUT
550000.00

INPUT
50000 10
OUTPUT
500000.00
```

Is there a way to represent the amount of money according to n?

Comment: You do not describe what the data values represent, and you've not shown any code. Please show your attempt. SO is not in the (give away) business of doing your homework. Note: "buy 3 get 1 free" is not BOGO... more BTGF ("Buy Three Get Four")...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I'm sorry but it's not homework, it's just an optional side practice question that I find hard to think about and would love to discuss. The thing is I was struggling with the math behind it, and I'll normally code after I've had the equation in my head, but I just couldn't find the right equation . That's why there is no code shown

Comment: One way to understand a problem is to write down a few examples. Consider: Customer wants 15 items. Store offers "buy 5 get 6"... 15%6 = 3... Customer pays for 2x5, gets 2x6 and needs to pay for 3 more (w/o any bonus received)... Work it out on paper for a few examples...

Comment: NB: Consider: Customer wants 3. Store offers BOGO... Customer must pay for 2, and walk out with 3 leaving 1 freebie behind in the store... Silly customer...

Comment: If customer buys `n` products with an offer x get y the amount for cost purposes is `n - (n >= x ? y : 0)` which you can write as `n - (n >= x) * y  .  If offers can be combined then you need you need `n - (n / x) * y` where (n / x) is regular truncated integer division.

Comment: @Fe2O3 "Silly customer..." Well, not always. I need 3 tons of gravel for a (small) building project in my home. With BOGO I can get 4 tons at the same price as 3 tons but what am I going to do with 1 tons extra gravel that I don't have room or need for?

Comment: @SupportUkraine What to do? Put the extra ton up on eBay (at 3/4 the price of 1 tone) selling to someone who only needs 1 ton... "Delivery not included." `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

If you buy 0 to x products, you pay for 0 to x. If you buy x+1 to x+y, you pay for x. Then the cycle starts over.

If you want n products, that is floor(n/(x+y)) whole cycles, for which you pay for x products in each cycle, plus a remainder r = n − floor(n/(x+y))•(x+y). For the remainder, you pay for r products if r is in 0 to x or pay for x products if r is in x+1 to x+y.

If p is the price of one product, the total is floor(n/(x+y))•x•p + r•p or floor(n/(x+y))•x•p + x•p, according to which interval r is in.

Answer (score 0):

With these definitions:

```
x is the number of items you need to buy to get the discount

y is the number of items you get as discount

n is the number of item you need in total
```

then you are looking for two integer numbers so that

```
n = F * (x + y) + R
```

where

```
F is is the number of times you can use the discount offer, i.e. get x+y items

R is the number of items you need to buy without getting discount.
Notice that R will always be less than x+y
```

Now

```
n = F * (x + y) + R
```

can be re-written as

```
n / (x + y) = F + R / (x + y)
```

Since we are dealing with integer math where results are rounded towards zero and `R` is always less than `x + y` this leads to:

```
n / (x + y) = F
```

and then you can get `R` by doing

```
R = n - F * (x + y)
```

If `p` is the price for a single item, you can calculate the total as:

```
total = p * x * F + p * R
```

So in C code you can do:

```
unsigned x = get_input();
unsigned y = get_input();
unsigned p = get_input();

unsigned F = n / (x + y);
unsigned R = n - F * (x + y);
unsigned total = p * x * F + p * R;
```

But notice... depending on the "rules" the above will not always give the lowest `total`.

The above assumes the "rules" to be:

1. When entitled to a discount, you either has to accept all `y` discount items or refuse the discount (i.e. get zero items).
2. That you must end up with exactly `n` items.

If the rules are changed a bit so that it's allowed to end up with **at least** `n` items, there must be a special handling for cases with `y` greater than `x` to reach the lowest `total` price.

Something like:

```
unsigned F = (y > x) ? 1 + n / (x + y) : n / (x + y);
unsigned R = (y > x) ? 0 : n - F * (x + y);
unsigned total = p * x * F + p * R;
```